# Where did rosbagmigration go in Fuerte?

Tags: rosbag, ros-fuerte, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Electric, `rosbagmigration` was a package inside `ros_comm`.

Where did it go in Fuerte?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27636/where-did-rosbagmigration-go-in-fuerte?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2012-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbagmigration was deprecated in ROS Diamondback:

http://ros.org/wiki/rosbagmigration

Fuerte finally removes it for good.

http://ros.org/wiki/rosbag/migration

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1